# smarttable get all rows

Tags: sapui5

I have a SmartTable control (with tableType="Table") in a custom app (sapui5 version 1.71).
The xml view (Main) has a filter, which when executed correctly brings the data via custom odata service and shows in the table. This part works as expected. Table threshold is set to 10k.

We are not selecting any rows on the Main view's smarttable (underlying Table has selectionMode="None").
The requirement is to have a 'summarise' button on the Main view that when pressed will show a Summary view (route navigation) with summarised information based on some columns (not keys).

How to get all the data from the Main's view smarttable?

getRows() method of the underlying table returns only visible rows.

I don't want to switch to use ui.table.Table as there are some nice features you get for free for a SmartTable.

Many thanks,
Wojciech

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same requirement. It's strange that UI5 makes it so hard to achieve something which is very basic. The code below is from my project but it gives the basic gist:

```
            var allItems = oSmartTable.getTable().getItems();
            var highestSortOrder = 1;
            for (var i=0; i<allItems.length; i++) {
                var anItem = allItems[i];
                var sPath = anItem.getBindingContext().sPath;
                var currentObject = oSmartTable.getModel().getObject(sPath);
                var currentSortOrder = currentObject.SORTORDER;
                if (null !== currentSortOrder) {
                    if (currentSortOrder > highestSortOrder) {
                        highestSortOrder = currentSortOrder;
                    }
                }
            }
```